# String list in tikz foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw some repeated with PGF/Tikz, and I'm using a `foreach`.
Problem: each line has, on the right, a description, which is a string of text - which may be somewhat long and contain commas or math expressions.

How can I create a list of strings, iterating over it and use each string as node text?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  This will also help to clarify the question.

Comment: Without a MWE, all I suggest is enclosing the strings within a curly braces: `{}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Actually the curly braces was exactly what I was looking for! - Sorry, but using LyX I'm pretty untrained about LaTeX.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To solve this problem was sufficient to use curly braces around the strings, as Peter Grill suggested:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \c [count=\x from 0] in {{a,f},{b,o},{c,o},{d,b},{e,a},{f,r}} 
        \node at (0,\x) {\c};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks Peter!