# List of strings for tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, strings

at first my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\johnlist{{ala},{bla},{cla}}
% \def\johnlist{2,3,5,7} %This instead of the line above works...

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] at (0,0) {\pgfmathparse{{\johnlist}[1]}\pgfmathresult};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `ala' (in '{{ala},{bla},{cla}}
```

I've read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35082/string-list-in-tikz-foreach) and it works, but it's not what I need!

I've read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45040/pgf-tikz-how-to-store-strings-in-array) too and the accepted answer might possibly work, but I can't believe there's no better way! [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45059/70553) answer looks promising, but doesn't work either...

Well, I'm searching for hours now and am already proud that I could isolate the error so far, but I'm really getting annoyed now and would greatly appreciate some help!!

Comment: as posted the MWE makes a single circled 3 (for some reason) you don't say what output you want from the commented version.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it should do... But I can't use the line that is commented out to define the "johnslist"-array, which is what I really want...

Comment: I changed the MWE, I think it should be easier to understand now!?

Comment: Your commented list has only one pair of braces. You need `{{2,3,5,7}}`. For otherwise text should be inside double quotes `{{"a","b"}}` etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings should be quoted, not braced:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\johnlist{{"ala","bla","cla"}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] at (0,0) {\pgfmathparse{\johnlist[1]}\pgfmathresult};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the additional braces in the definition of `\johnlist` and the removal of those around `\johnlist` in `\pgfmathparse`, according to the syntax found on page 934 of the manual.

Comment: Well that works, thanks so far! Unfortunately it seems like I can't get it to work in my real project, so I'll perhaps come up with another question...