# Array of strings as text for nodes in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, strings

I have a rather large number of nodes n1, n2,...,n41, all of them containing expresions like `\textcolor{c}{blabla}` and `\large` etc.
It seem when storing all these texts in an array of the form described in
[List of strings for tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249071/list-of-strings-for-tikzpicture)
namely

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\johnlist{{"ala","bla","cla"}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] at (0,0) {\pgfmathparse{\johnlist[1]}\pgfmathresult};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

does not work if for example "bla" is replaced by `\Large bla`.

So the question is how to create lists or arrays of TeX-compatible strings?

Comment: Is `\large\pgfmathparse` acceptable?

Comment: Instead of \Large bla you should use `font=\Large` key on the node.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\green}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}   

\begin{document}
\newcommand\johnlist{{"\noexpand\Huge ala","\noexpand\green{{bla}}","\noexpand\bfseries\noexpand\Large cla"}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,1,2}
{
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] at (\i,0) {\pgfmathparse{\johnlist[\i]}\pgfmathresult};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but it seems that
1) `\noexpand\textbf{bla}` gives no bold text and
2) `\noexpand\textcolor{green}{bla}` gives error messages.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger I modified the answer. And sorry, your point 2) did not show. (This happened already before and is really annoying.) Anyway, sorry for my comment.

Comment: I see: lower level commands will do it.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger No, the difference are the brackets. `\noexpand\textbf{{...}}` also works. You can either use a command that does not require brackets such as `\bfseries` (with syntax `{\bfseries ...}`, or commands like `\textbf`, but then you have to put two braces, `\textbf{{...}}` instead of `\textbf{...}`. This is because the `\noexpand` makes TeX to skip over the nex command.

Answer (score 4):

My impression is that the handling of arrays in PGF is quite fragile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setlist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_clear_new:c { l_jens_#1_array_clist }
  \clist_set:cn { l_jens_#1_array_clist } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\listitem}{mm}
 {
  \clist_item:cn { l_jens_#1_array_clist } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\setlist{john}{\textbf{ala},\Huge bla,\large cla}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] at (0,0) {\listitem{john}{1}};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] at (1,0) {\listitem{john}{2}};
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] at (2,0) {\listitem{john}{3}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in { 0,1,2 } {
  \node[shape=circle,draw=black] at (\x,0) {\listitem{john}{\x+1}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that you can do arithmetic operations on the second argument to `\listitem`. The indexing starts from 1.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could hack the random list stuff, although specifying items requires braces rather than commas, and indexing starts at 1:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\def\pgfmathrandomlistitem#1#2{\pgfmathparse{int(#2)}%
  \csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\pgfmathresult\endcsname}

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{list1}{%
  {\tiny\textcolor{red}{ala}}
  {\small\textcolor{green}{bla}}
  {\large\textcolor{blue}{cla}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,2}
  \node [circle, draw] at (0, \i) {\pgfmathrandomlistitem{list1}{\i+1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In
  [1]: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V-o2E3tdh7VflV1IVXSk8QAbpPhHfqv2

you may find a ``real example´´ processed first by **egreg**´s method and then -- by easy modifications -- by **Mark Wibrows**´ method.